# AppleScript to add Application to Full Disk Access

Tags: applescript

To install Sophos Endpoint on MacOS, it requires adding Sophos Files to Full Disc Access.

I have a beginning script to open Security Preferences, go to Security & Privacy, go to the Privacy tab, Unlock, and the ability to put a check in existing applications in Full Disk Access.  I however am stuck in "adding an application" where i can add the application to the existing list.

I would need to pull from /Library/ and from /Applications/Sophos/

The script I have gets me into Privacy\Full Disk Access and unlocked, but I can't get it to click the "Add an application".

Comment: Actually the purpose of those security settings is that the user in person grants the permission, not a script

Comment: Hi Vadian,  It does let me select an application if it is already present and put a check in it.  I just don't know the commands to click the "add an application" button and then select the file through Finder.  I got the base script from here so I was hoping that there was more in AppleScript that would do the extra stuff since the devices I need to run it on are all remote devices.

Comment: The base script i am using is from a post "Accessibility to the Privacy tab using AppleScript" from user3439894.  I just need to add a step before the "click checkbox 1" section which would be clicking the "add an application".  I tried to use "click button "Add an application", but it does not recognize that as a button.  I'm not sure what code should be used to click the "+" sign.

Comment: "Add" button in the System Preferences is activated only when the mouse pointer goes over it. So, to click it, you need first get **its position** using reference to button, then click on that position using **mouse tool**.

Comment: And, this button doesn't have the name. You can identify it using its help or description. Using description, for example:  **set addButton to 1st button of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Security & Privacy" whose description is "add"**. Then, **set itsPosition to position of addButton**, then click on this position using some mouse tool, like cliclick

Comment: I need this for `cron`. My jobs were mysteriously failing on my new Macbook.